# I have to segment an audio signal into several segments and I should have access to each and every segment

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

```
[y,fs] = audioread('sound.wav'); 
n = numel(y);
ns = 2;
b=n/ns;
c = mat2cell(y,diff([0:b:n-1,n]));
```

Here from the above code, I cut the signal into two equal halves. what if I have a signal of 5sec and I want segments of 2s,2s,1s using Matlab. Can someone help me in this regard?
By using the above code I am not able to segment if the n is od.

Comment: You have to use sample rate `fs`, which is given in Hz. This means that an array of length `fs` holds exactly 1s of music. This means to get the first two seconds you can use: `y(1:2*fs,:)`

Comment: thank you for your reply but what about the leftover part of the signal. I can have  segments of 2s by using a loop for as many numbers of segments but how to retrieve the last part of the signal that is left.

Comment: You can use something like `y(2*fs*s+1:end,:)` where s is the number of previous segments.

Comment: thank you I will try it out